# How does this function change a constant reference?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I can't work this simple problem out.
I have a class called Directory, and I am having a problem with operator overloading.

The Class:

```
class Directory
    {
    private:
        std::string path;
        bool parent;
        sajat::Directory* parentDirectory;
        std::vector<Directory> innerDirectories;
        std::vector<File> innerFiles;
    public:
        //...constructors
        
        Directory& operator=(const Directory&);

        //...other member functions
        Directory& findInnerDirectory(WIN32_FIND_DATAA&);

        
    };
```

The function I am experiencing the problem with:

```
Directory& Directory::operator=(const Directory& that) {
    if (this == &that)
        return *this;
    innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories;//after this line, it modifies that.path value
    innerFiles = that.innerFiles;
    path = that.path; //after this line, it modifies that.parentDirectory (not the address, but the value under the address)
    parent = that.parent;
    parentDirectory = that.parentDirectory;
    return *this;
}
```

The line that calls the assignment operator:

```
current = current.findInnerDirectory(findData);
```

The types are both Directories, the findInnerDirectory function returns a Directory inside innerDirectories vector (it seems to work fine) (I am trying to assign a child to its parent)

I can't seem to understand, how this **modifies** the "**that**" parameter, since it should be a **constant** reference.
I am using C++14 and Visual Studio 2022

I attached some photos of the values, maybe this helps.

[the values after calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1DgA.png)

[the values after line "innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories;"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6bhG.png)

[the values after line "path = that.path;"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD5ZU.png)

I have tried saving all the values in local variables, but the problem stayed, it changed the at the same lines (I assigned the copied values)
I read that the VS watch can sometimes show bad values, but the problem stays, even after the specified function has ended.

**Desired behavior:**

I would like to assign a Directory to its child, with a correct output.

**Code necessary to reproduce the problem:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
class Directory
{
private:
    std::string path;
    bool parent;
    Directory* parentDirectory;
    std::vector<Directory> innerDirectories;
    std::vector<std::string> innerFiles; //I changed the type File to string, to make it runnable
public:
    //constructors
    Directory(std::string path, bool isItParent, Directory* parentDirectory) : path(path), parent(isItParent), parentDirectory(parentDirectory) {}

    //the function I am having the problem with:
    Directory& operator=(const Directory& that) {
        if (this == &that)
            return *this;
        innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories; //after this line, it changes the that.path to ""
        innerFiles = that.innerFiles;
        path = that.path; // after this line, it changes the
        parent = that.parent;
        parentDirectory = that.parentDirectory;
        return *this; //so the function returns a Directory, which has the parent itself
    }


    //..other member functions
    Directory& findInnerDirectory(WIN32_FIND_DATAA& findData) {
        for (int i = 0; i < innerDirectories.size(); i++) {
            if (innerDirectories[i].path == findData.cFileName)
                return innerDirectories[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Directory& addInnerDirectory(WIN32_FIND_DATAA& findData, bool isItParent) {
        Directory temp(findData.cFileName, isItParent, this);
        innerDirectories.push_back(temp);
        return innerDirectories.back();
    }
};
//skip if directory itself,  or parent directory
bool isLink(WIN32_FIND_DATAA& findData) {
    if (std::strcmp(findData.cFileName, ".") == 0 || std::strcmp(findData.cFileName, "..") == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

Directory scanPath(const std::string& path) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA findData;
    std::string fullPath = path + "\\*";
    Directory current(path, 1, nullptr);
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(fullPath.c_str(), &findData);
    while(isLink(findData))
        FindNextFileA(hFind, &findData);
    current.addInnerDirectory(findData, 0);
    current = current.findInnerDirectory(findData); //the line that calls the assignment 
    return current;
}

int main(void) {
    std::string path = "path"; //it needs a folder, that has another folder inside
    Directory test = scanPath(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some sort of undefined behavior in your code.  Can you [edit] this to contain a [mre]?

Comment: Please try and avoid using notation that is also C++ syntax to highlight problems. If you can, use a comment.

Comment: I would guess that either `this` or `that` is not a reference to a real `Directory`, and is instead a reference to a `Directory` that has gone out of scope.

Comment: Where does `that` get modified here? This appears to be copying things into `this`.

Comment: That `findInnerDirectory` returns a reference looks *very* suspicious.

Comment: Is `findInnerDirectory` returning a reference to an element of `innerDirectories` (or recursively to any depth through `innerDirectories`)? If so, the line `innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories;` potentially invalidates the reference `that`, and your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is the `sajat::Directory* parentDirectory` of **that** equal to **this**?  Because if `that.parentDirectory == this`, then changes to `this` will appear to affect `that` because `that.parentDirecty` is `this`.  (The `const` isn't as "constant-ness" as it may imply.  And it certainly isn't transitive, without special effort to mimic transitive `const`.)

Comment: You've got undefined behaviour, since `that` does not survive `innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories;`, if it's a descendant directory of the lhs of the assignment. That expression must be the last thing you do in the copy assignment operator. You'll probably need to do some check for this scenario anyways to be able to remove a parent pointer that points to an invalid parent object; You could decide to simply throw an exception in this case, if you want to avoid this scenario alltogether...

Comment: @OP *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that as UB. The program may just crash."*

Comment: @NathanOliver I added some reproducable code. Thanks for asking

Comment: @fabian yes, but I am building a tree of the directories, so I should be able to "step down" into its child, how should I avoid this?

Comment: You will probably have to distinguish the between the root directory and the current directory. E.g. `Directory root(path, 1, nullptr); Directory * current = &root;` ... `current = &current.findInnerDirectory(findData);`

Answer (score 0):

Because `that` is bound to an element of `innerDirectories`, and `that.innerDirectories` is empty, the line `innerDirectories = that.innerDirectories;` invalidates the reference `that`, and your program has undefined behaviour.

The simplest fix would be to change `scanPath` to not overwrite a `Directory`, and just return.

```
Directory scanPath(const std::string& path) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA findData;
    std::string fullPath = path + "\\*";
    Directory current(path, 1, nullptr);
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(fullPath.c_str(), &findData);
    while(isLink(findData))
        FindNextFileA(hFind, &findData);
    current.addInnerDirectory(findData, 0);
    return current.findInnerDirectory(findData); 
}
```

Whatever you do, you can't have `Directory* parentDirectory;`, because the parent is destroyed at the end of `scanPath`, and that pointer will become invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is that scanPath should be a much bigger function, I use DFS to find files in a directory and then find duplicate files. (I just cut the end of the function scanPath, to make the program runnable, to demonstrate the problem.) Is there a possible way to fix this assignment operator?

Comment: @ZoltànTurcsán You can't have `current = current.findInnerDirectory(findData);` with the definition in the question, but I can't suggest improvements to the code you haven't shown.